# Forming a byte string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I am creating a method in Python whereby it will take a number which will form a byte string that will then get sent to the Arduino. However whenever I try, the escape character is always included in the final byte string.

Here is the snippet of the code I am using:

```
num = 5
my_str = '\\x4' + str(num)
my_str.encode('utf-8')
```

Result:

```
b'\\x45'
```

I tried another method:

```
num2 = 5
byte1 = b'\\x4'
byte2 = bytes(str(num2), 'ISO-8859-1')
new_byte = byte1 + byte2
new_byte
```

Result:

```
b'\\x45'
```

Trying yet in a different way:

```
num = 5
u = chr(92) + 'x4' + str(num)
u.encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

Result:

```
b'\\x45'
```

I would like to get the byte string to be b'\x45' without the escape character but not really sure what I have missed. I will appreciate any pointers on how I can achieve this.

Comment: Will `num` always be a digit between 0 and 9? Could it also be a string representing a hex digit like `"a"` or `"f"`?

Comment: `num2 = 5`, `b = chr(ord('\x40')+num2)`, `hex(ord(b))` -> `'0x45'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have already escaped the backslash. It is not recommended to construct a literal using an unknown variable, especially if there's a simpler way, which there is:

```
def make_into_bytes(n):
    return bytes([64 + n])

print(make_into_bytes(5))
```

This outputs

```
b'E'
```

Note that this isn't a bug, as this is simply the value of 0x45:

```
>>> b'\x45'
b'E'
```

The way this function works is basically just doing it by hand. Prepending '4' to a hex string (of length 1) is the same as adding 4 * 16 to it, which is 64. I then construct a bytes object out of this. Note that I assume n is an integer, as in your code. If n should be a digit like `'a'`, this would be the integer `10`.

If you want it to work on hex digits, rather than on integer digits, you would need to change it to this:

```
def make_into_bytes(n):
    return bytes([64 + int(n, 16)])

print(make_into_bytes('5'))
print(make_into_bytes('a'))
```

with output

```
b'E'
b'J'
```

This quite simply converts the digit from base 16 first.

Comment: Regarding "It is very difficult to construct a literal using an unknown variable" – that's not true.  It's very easy, but not the recommended way of solving this problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use `codecs.decode("\\x45", "unicode_escape")` to parse a string containing escapes.

Comment: Good point! Thanks, I'll edit my answer. Also, I'm sorry if I sounded blunt earlier. I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function `chr()` to convert an integer to the corresponding character:

```
>>> chr(0x40 + 5)
'E'
```

Alternatively, if you just one to get the n-th letter of the alphabet, it might be more readable to use `str.ascii_uppercase`

```
>>> string.ascii_uppercase[5 - 1]
'E'
```

Note that the results in this answer are strings in Python 3, not `bytes` objects.  Simply calling `.encode()` on them will convert them to `bytes`.

Comment: This isn't a bytes object

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I know it isn't, but it's trivial to convert into one.  I answered the part of the question the OP struggled with, but I'll point it out explicitly.